# Coerce ggplot2 to plot bar plot with manually specified fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Data: [Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eiuonpzrlw314f8/data.csv)
Data1: [Data1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4pnsbr8v96ceqv/data1.csv)

Code:

```
CashSurDef <- ggplot(data=wdiSSA_CashSurDef.df,aes(x=Country.Name, y=avg, fill=colour))
CashSurDef <- CashSurDef + geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(),alpha=.75) + theme_bw()
CashSurDef <- CashSurDef + scale_fill_manual(breaks = wdiSSA_CashSurDef.df$Country.Name,
                                    values = unique(as.character(wdiSSA_CashSurDef.df$colour)))
CashSurDef <- CashSurDef + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-25,25,2.5)) + geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", colour="blue", size=1.1)
CashSurDef <- CashSurDef + labs(title="Cash surplus/deficit (% of GDP) (Average 2005-2012)", y="", x="Country") + coord_flip() 
CashSurDef <- CashSurDef + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(2), hjust=0.5, vjust=1.5),
                            axis.text.x=element_text(color="black", size=rel(1.8), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5),
                            axis.text.y=element_text(color="black", size=rel(1.8), hjust=1),
                            axis.title.x=element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=rel(1.6), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.2),
                            axis.title.y=element_text(color="black", size=rel(1.6), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.2),
                            strip.text=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(1.8)),
                            legend.text=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(1.25)),
                            legend.title=element_blank(),
                            legend.position="bottom")
CashSurDef
```

Code1:

```
Unemploy <- ggplot(data=wdiSSA_Unemploy.df,aes(x=Country.Name, y=avg, fill=colour))
Unemploy <- Unemploy + geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(),alpha=.75) + theme_bw()
Unemploy <- Unemploy + scale_fill_manual(breaks = wdiSSA_Unemploy.df$Country.Name,
                                    values = unique(as.character(wdiSSA_Unemploy.df$colour)))
Unemploy <- Unemploy + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,35,5)) + geom_hline(yintercept=5, linetype="dashed", colour="blue", size=1.1)
Unemploy <- Unemploy + labs(title="Average unemployment rate (2005-2012), total (%)", y="", x="Country") + coord_flip()
Unemploy <- Unemploy + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(2), hjust=0.5, vjust=1.5),
                        axis.text.x=element_text(color="black", size=rel(1.8), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.5),
                        axis.text.y=element_text(color="black", size=rel(1.8), hjust=1),
                        axis.title.x=element_text(face="bold", color="black", size=rel(1.6), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.2),
                        axis.title.y=element_text(color="black", size=rel(1.6), hjust=0.5, vjust=0.2),
                        strip.text=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(1.8)),
                        legend.text=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(1.25)),
                        legend.title=element_blank(),
                        legend.position="bottom")
Unemploy
```

Result: [image: Result]
Result1: [image: Result1]

Question: I am trying to plot the data and use the predefined fill captured by the column "colour" in "Data", and which was added based on the conditional statement: `if(avg>0, tan3, grey)`. When I plot though, the colour filling gets reversed as you may observe in the picture "Result". I applied the same method for other variables in my data (cf. "Data1", "Result1"), and it worked perfectly. Any thoughts, suggestions?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you left out the code to reorder the country names factor by avg, so your code does not produce these plots.

Second, using a color name in a data frame doesn't help you. `ggplot(...,aes(fill=...))` interprets that column as a factor to distinguish between groups. It assigns it's own colors, which is why you need to use `scale_fill_manual(...)` to actually set the colors to something you want.

Third, you don't need `breaks=...` in the call to `scale_fill_manual(...)`.

Fourth, and this is the answer to your main question, `unique(as.character(df$colours))` returns the colors in an order based on when they appear in `df`. In the cash flow table, `tan3` appears first, in the unemployment table `grey` appears first. One way around this is to replace your calls

```
scale_fill_manual(breaks = df$Country.Name, values = unique(df$colour)))
```

with

```
scale_fill_manual(values = 
            as.character(setNames(unique(df$colour),unique(df$colour))))
```

with `df` replaced by the names of your data frames. This creates a *named vector* of colors, where the color name and the color are the same, e.g.

```
c(tan3="tan3",grey="grey",NA)
```

which will associate the colors properly.

Finally, IMO you would be much better off doing something like this (here I'm using `cash` as the name of your dataframe)

```
...
ggplot(data=cash,aes(x=Country.Name, y=avg, 
                     fill=(ifelse(avg>0,"Positive","Negative"))))+
   geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(),
            alpha=.75) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c(Positive="grey",Negative="tan3"))
...
```